# dependent drop downlist generation

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a dependent dropdown list using ajax and php but not able to get the desired result

here is my code of ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<title>findperson</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
var x=ddl1.value;
var service;
var url='service.php?data='+x;
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new
ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET",url);
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
service=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
for (var i=0;i<service.length;i++ ){
var opt = service[i];
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.textContent = opt;
el.value = opt;
ddl2.appendChild(el);
}

}
}
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="problem.php">
<select name="city" id="city"       onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('service'))">
<option selected="selected" value="">City</option>
<option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
<option value="lucknow">Lucknow</option>
</select>
<select id="service">
<option selected="selected" value="">Service</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="proceed" value="Next"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my php file

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$db=new db();
$sql=$db->database_initialise();
$city=$_GET['data'];
$query="select service_name from service_offered where city='$city'";
if($result=$sql->query($query)){
if($result->num_rows >0){
    $i=0;
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
        $service[$i]=$row[0];
        $i++;
    }
  }
}
var_dump($service);
?>
```

problem is that in second dropdown list no changes occur on selecting a city

Comment: what data contain  varible service in javascript file.
You can call console.log(service);

Comment: Thanks it worked out

Answer (score 0):

Replace var_dump($service)

```
echo json_encode($service);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are returning the `$service` array from your PHP and accessing it in your AJAX as a string. `service=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;` returns a **string** object. In your for loop it looks like you are trying to index through an **array**. However, you can't index through a string like that and get what you are expecting.
The best thing is to use `echo json_encode($service);` like Leo suggested, then in your AJAX transform the `responseText` by using `JSON.parse`

```
var json = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
```

Then in the for loop

```
var opt = json[/*i or column name*/];
```

or

```
var opt = json.service_name[i];
```

Note: To return a JSON string in PHP, you have to set the header: `header("Content-type: application/json");`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems here:

- your PHP is not sending the correct response. What you want to do is have PHP send a JSON response.
- once PHP sends this JSON response, you then need to parse this into an object
- Once your response is in object format, you can then iterate through the results.

Try this:

**PHP** (this is an example of what will be returned from your DB):

```
$response = array(
    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "something"
    )
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

**JS:**

```
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1, ddl2) {
    var url = 'submit.php?data=' + ddl1.value;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    var opt = obj[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt.name;
                    el.value = opt.id;
                    ddl2.appendChild(el);
                }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```